# Laravel eloquent whereHas where first date equals a specific date

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two related tables:

`projects`:

```
| id | name    |
| 1  | Test    |
| 2  | Example |
```

`project_dates`:

```
| id | project_id     | date       |
| 1  | 1              | 2020-02-01 |
| 2  | 1              | 2020-02-10 |
| 3  | 1              | 2020-01-25 |
| 4  | 2              | 2020-01-10 |
| 5  | 2              | 2019-12-15 |
```

Now for example I would like to get all `projects` where the first date of `project_dates` is equal to `2020-01-25`. So I tried the following:

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('dates', function($query) {
   $query->whereRaw("MIN(date) = '2020-01-25'");
});
```

But this returns the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function

which revers to `MIN(date)`. So my question remains how can I get all projects with the first date being equal to `2020-01-25` or any other specific date. From the example above I would expect to get the project with id `1` since the first date of `2` is `2019-12-15`

I know that is possible to use a `subqueryjoin` however I feel like doing 2 queries shouldn't be required.

```
$firstDates = ProjectDate::groupBy('project_id')
->selectRaw('project_id, MIN(date) as first_date'); 

Project::joinSub($firstDates, 'first_dates', function($join){
    $join->on('first_dates.project_id', '=', 'project.id')
         ->where('first_date', '=','2020-01-25');
})->get();
```

Comment: use `whereDate()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Comment: @BohdanPetrenko isn't that for just on the table itself? This is about a related table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `where` aggregate function with `groupBy`, try to use `havingRaw` instead:

```php
$projects = Project::whereHas('dates', function($query) {
   $query->havingRaw("MIN(date) = ?", ['2020-01-25']);
});
// Or
$projects = Project::whereHas('dates', function($query) {
   $query->having(DB::raw("MIN(date)"), '2020-01-25');
});

$projects = Project::whereHas('dates', function($query) {
   $query->having(DB::raw("MIN(date)"), '2020-01-25')
     ->groupBy( 'project_dates.id' ); // For sql_mode=only_full_group_by
});
```